# Generating an xpath expression from a linq query

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I will have a linq query that will be made out of objects and I have to get this linq query transformed to a XPath query so that I can use it against a column in the db.

If there is a possibility for this in C#.Net, please let me know the references.

something like this

```
var query = order.select(o=>o.productid < 100 && o.productid > 5)
```

Which will give me somevalue like this `/order[@productid >5 and @productid < 100`

Comment: I don't think there's anything built into the framework... you could build it yourself, but it would be a lot of work.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Can you give me some pointers like how to identity the expressions in a linq query. Should we be required to use reflection. This is something similar to what elastic search offers to query the stored data using linq, but they are doing it via objects and we have to do it against a column in the db

Comment: You should look into *expression trees*. (Search on MSDN to find a lot of documentation.) Although you'd also want to use `Where` instead of `Select`, to filter. If you're only interesting in the filter side of things, you probably don't need to consider all of LINQ - *just* expression trees. But I would really expect this to be a big job - are you sure it's going to be worth the time?

Comment: This doesn't sound possible to me. LINQ and XPath are extremely different animals, and I believe that there's a very limited subset of LINQ queries that even have XPath equivalents. In your example alone, how would it know that it's `@productid` (attribute) and not `productid` (element)? What if there are XML namespaces involved? Perhaps there is some hope in translating a limited subset of LINQ-to-XML to XPath, but not LINQ-to-Objects.